# Implement foreach logic in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a table `Fruit` like this:

| Name | Property | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Price | $5 |
| Apple | Color | Red |
| Apple | Quantity | 20 |
| Pear | Price | $5 |
| Pear | Color | Kelly |
| Pear | Weight | 50g |
| Pear | Quality | Good |

Now I want to select all records of `Pear` that are different from `Apple` in either `Property` or `Value` (The result will be the last 3 rows)

In C# it will be

```
foreach(var apple in apples)
{
   var result = pears.All(pear => pear.Property != apple.Property && pear.Value != apple.Value)
}
```

In SQL Server I tried this but failed:

```
    Select * from Fruit where Name = 'Pear'
and exists
(select 1 from Fruit t where t.Name = 'Apple'
and t.Property <> Fruit.Property
and t.Value <> Fruit.Value)
```

How should I correct the SQL statement? Thanks.

Comment: That's a very poorly normalized table! If this is from a real-life application you really should do something about it.

Comment: But apples can be red and green (and other colours). How would you know what property belongs to another? Your design needs fixing here.

Comment: Apologizes. That's my first time to use Table here. It looked OK when I previewed it. But lost format after I posted this question. Thanks for the comment and edit.

Comment: @GertArnold isn't talking about how you presented the tables they are saying your design in your actual database is flawed.

Comment: EAV strikes again! If you are designing your own database, then research that term to understand the consequences and the very real problems you will face trying to extract meaningful information from it.

Comment: @Larnu Oh I see. Will not design such table in reality. Just for a test of some sql statements. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from fruit f
where f.name = 'Pear' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from fruit f2
                  where f2.name = 'Apple' and
                        f2.property = f.property and
                        f2.value = f.value
                 );
```